# How to convert ECDSA DER encoded signature data to microsoft CNG supported format?

Tags: c++, cryptography, elliptic-curve, cng

I am preparing a minidriver to perform sign in smartcard using `NCryptSignHash` function of Microsoft CNG.

When I perform sign with an SECP521R1 EC key in smartcard it generates a sign data with length of 139 as ECC signed data format:

```
ECDSASignature ::= SEQUENCE {
    r   INTEGER,
    s   INTEGER
}
```

Sample signed data is

```
308188024201A2001E9C0151C55BCA188F201020A84180B339E61EDE61F6EAD0B277321CAB81C87DAFC2AC65D542D0D0B01C3C5E25E9209C47CFDDFD5BBCAFA0D2AF2E7FD86701024200C103E534BD1378D8B6F5652FB058F7D5045615DCD940462ED0F923073076EF581210D0DD95BF2891358F5F743DB2EC009A0608CEFAA9A40AF41718881D0A26A7F4
```

But when I perform Sign using `MS_KEY_STORAGE_PROVIDER` it generates a sign with length of 132 byte.

What is the procedure to reduce the sign data size from 139 to 132?

Comment: So far I understand removing the DER headers '3081880242' and at middle '0242' can make the size 132. Can anyone suggest me any related document.

Comment: Oops.  I had the direction wrong in the first version of this comment.  If the MS CNG signature is only 132 bytes, then it doesn't have any room left for DER/ASN.1 encoding.  P-521 requires 66 bytes per coordinate.  This ASN.1/DER parser is handy:  https://lapo.it/asn1js/#308188024201A2001E9C0151C55BCA188F201020A84180B339E61EDE61F6EAD0B277321CAB81C87DAFC2AC65D542D0D0B01C3C5E25E9209C47CFDDFD5BBCAFA0D2AF2E7FD86701024200C103E534BD1378D8B6F5652FB058F7D5045615DCD940462ED0F923073076EF581210D0DD95BF2891358F5F743DB2EC009A0608CEFAA9A40AF41718881D0A26A7F4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your input is an X9.62 signature format which is a SEQUENCE containing two ASN.1 / DER encoded signatures. These integers are variable sized, signed, big endian numbers. They are encoded in the minimum number of bytes. This means that the size of the encoding can vary.

The 139 bytes is common because it assumes the maximum size of the encoding for `r` and `s`. These values are computed using *modular* arithmetic and they can therefore contain any number of bits, up to the number of bits of order `n`, which is the same as the key size, 521 bits.

---

The 132 bytes are specified by ISO/IEC 7816-8 / IEEE P1363 which is a standard that deals with signatures for smart cards. The signature consists of the concatenation of `r` and `s`, where `r` and `s` are encoded as the minimum number of bytes to display a value of the same size as the order, in bytes. The `r` and `s` are statically sized, unsigned, big endian numbers.

The calculation of the number of bytes of `r` or `s` is `ceil((double) n / 8)` or `(n + 8 - 1) / 8` where 8 is the number of bits in a byte. So if the elliptic curve is 521 bits then the resulting size is 66 bytes, and together they therefore consume 132 bytes.

---

Now on to the decoding. There are multiple ways of handling this: perform a full ASN.1 parse, obtain the integers and then encode them back again in the ISO 7816-8 form is the most logical one.

However, you can also see that you could simply copy bytes as `r` and `s` will always be non-negative (and thus unsigned) and big endian. So you just need to compensate for the size. Otherwise the only hard part is to be able to decode the length of the components within the X9.62 structure.

---

**Warning**: code in C# instead of C++ as I expected the main .NET language; language not indicated in question when I wrote the main part of the answer.

```C#
class ConvertECDSASignature
{
    private static int BYTE_SIZE_BITS = 8;
    private static byte ASN1_SEQUENCE = 0x30;
    private static byte ASN1_INTEGER = 0x02;

    public static byte[] lightweightConvertSignatureFromX9_62ToISO7816_8(int orderInBits, byte[] x9_62)
    {
        int offset = 0;
        if (x9_62[offset++] != ASN1_SEQUENCE)
        {
            throw new IllegalSignatureFormatException("Input is not a SEQUENCE");
        }

        int sequenceSize = parseLength(x9_62, offset, out offset);
        int sequenceValueOffset = offset;

        int nBytes = (orderInBits + BYTE_SIZE_BITS - 1) / BYTE_SIZE_BITS;
        byte[] iso7816_8 = new byte[2 * nBytes];

        // retrieve and copy r

        if (x9_62[offset++] != ASN1_INTEGER)
        {
            throw new IllegalSignatureFormatException("Input is not an INTEGER");
        }

        int rSize = parseLength(x9_62, offset, out offset);
        copyToStatic(x9_62, offset, rSize, iso7816_8, 0, nBytes);

        offset += rSize;

        // --- retrieve and copy s

        if (x9_62[offset++] != ASN1_INTEGER)
        {
            throw new IllegalSignatureFormatException("Input is not an INTEGER");
        }

        int sSize = parseLength(x9_62, offset, out offset);
        copyToStatic(x9_62, offset, sSize, iso7816_8, nBytes, nBytes);

        offset += sSize;

        if (offset != sequenceValueOffset + sequenceSize)
        {
            throw new IllegalSignatureFormatException("SEQUENCE is either too small or too large for the encoding of r and s"); 
        }

        return iso7816_8;
    }

    /**
     * Copies an variable sized, signed, big endian number to an array as static sized, unsigned, big endian number.
     * Assumes that the iso7816_8 buffer is zeroized from the iso7816_8Offset for nBytes.
     */
    private static void copyToStatic(byte[] sint, int sintOffset, int sintSize, byte[] iso7816_8, int iso7816_8Offset, int nBytes)
    {
        // if the integer starts with zero, then skip it
        if (sint[sintOffset] == 0x00)
        {
            sintOffset++;
            sintSize--;
        }

        // after skipping the zero byte then the integer must fit
        if (sintSize > nBytes)
        {
            throw new IllegalSignatureFormatException("Number format of r or s too large");
        }

        // copy it into the right place
        Array.Copy(sint, sintOffset, iso7816_8, iso7816_8Offset + nBytes - sintSize, sintSize);
    }

    /*
     * Standalone BER decoding of length value, up to 2^31 -1.
     */
    private static int parseLength(byte[] input, int startOffset, out int offset)
    {
        offset = startOffset;
        byte l1 = input[offset++];
        // --- return value of single byte length encoding
        if (l1 < 0x80)
        {
            return l1;
        }

        // otherwise the first byte of the length specifies the number of encoding bytes that follows
        int end = offset + l1 & 0x7F;

        uint result = 0;

        // --- skip leftmost zero bytes (for BER)
        while (offset < end)
        {
            if (input[offset] != 0x00)
            {
                break;
            }
            offset++;
        }

        // --- test against maximum value
        if (end - offset > sizeof(uint))
        {
            throw new IllegalSignatureFormatException("Length of TLV is too large");
        }

        // --- parse multi byte length encoding
        while (offset < end)
        {
            result = (result << BYTE_SIZE_BITS) ^ input[offset++];
        }

        // --- make sure that the uint isn't larger than an int can handle
        if (result > Int32.MaxValue)
        {
            throw new IllegalSignatureFormatException("Length of TLV is too large");
        }

        // --- return multi byte length encoding
        return (int) result;
    }
}
```

Note that the code is somewhat permissive in the fact that it doesn't require the *minimum* length encoding for the SEQUENCE and INTEGER length encoding (which it should).

It also allows wrongly encoded INTEGER values that are unnecessarily left-padded with zero bytes.

Neither of these issues should break the security of the algorithm but other libraries may and should be less permissive.

Comment: Whoops, I thought I read C#, my bad. Uh, can you try to port it to C++ yourself? I assumed C# because CNG is a .NET library and therefore often not used by C++.

Comment: I thought the question had the C# tag, too. That's why I added some .Net comments. BTW, I am out of upvotes so I owe you one for this post.

Comment: @jww Sorry, that was me. I added the tag because it only had the [tag:cng] tag, a .NET library for cryptographic ops.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks a lot for a lot of information.
I have also write my code almost as like your example code to decode.

Comment: Cool, glad to have been on help. Feel free to add the C++ to my answer so others can enjoy the C++ variant it as well.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the procedure to reduce the sign data size from 139 to 132?

You have an ASN.1 encoded signature (shown below). It is used by Java, OpenSSL  and some other libraries. You need the signature in P1363 format, which is a concatenation of `r || s`, without the ASN.1 encoding. P1363 is used by Crypto++ and a few other libraries. (There's another common signature format, and that is OpenPGP).

For the concatenation of `r || s`, both `r` and `s` must be 66 bytes because of secp-521r1 field element size on an octet boundary. That means the procedure is, you have to strip the outer `SEQUENCE`, and then strip the two `INTEGER`, and then concatenate the values of the two integers.

Your formatted `r || s` signature using your sample data will be:

```
01 A2 00 1E ... 7F D8 67 01 || 00 C1 03 E5 ... 0A 26 A7 F4
```

Microsoft .Net 2.0 has ASN.1 classes that allow you to manipulate ASN.1 encoded data. See [AsnEncodedData class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.asnencodeddata.aspx).

---

```
$ echo 08188024201A2001E9C0151C55BCA188F201020A84180B339E61EDE61F6EAD0B277321CAB
81C87DAFC2AC65D542D0D0B01C3C5E25E9209C47CFDDFD5BBCAFA0D2AF2E7FD86701024200C103E5
34BD1378D8B6F5652FB058F7D5045615DCD940462ED0F923073076EF581210D0DD95BF2891358F5F
743DB2EC009A0608CEFAA9A40AF41718881D0A26A7F4 | xxd -r -p > signature.bin

$ dumpasn1 signature.bin
  0 136: SEQUENCE {
  3  66:   INTEGER
       :     01 A2 00 1E 9C 01 51 C5 5B CA 18 8F 20 10 20 A8
       :     41 80 B3 39 E6 1E DE 61 F6 EA D0 B2 77 32 1C AB
       :     81 C8 7D AF C2 AC 65 D5 42 D0 D0 B0 1C 3C 5E 25
       :     E9 20 9C 47 CF DD FD 5B BC AF A0 D2 AF 2E 7F D8
       :     67 01
 71  66:   INTEGER
       :     00 C1 03 E5 34 BD 13 78 D8 B6 F5 65 2F B0 58 F7
       :     D5 04 56 15 DC D9 40 46 2E D0 F9 23 07 30 76 EF
       :     58 12 10 D0 DD 95 BF 28 91 35 8F 5F 74 3D B2 EC
       :     00 9A 06 08 CE FA A9 A4 0A F4 17 18 88 1D 0A 26
       :     A7 F4
       :   }

0 warnings, 0 errors.
```

---

Another noteworthy item is, .Net uses the XML format detailed in [RFC 3275, XML-Signature Syntax and Processing](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3275.txt). It is a different format than ASN.1, P1363, OpenPGP, CNG and other libraries.

The ASN.1 to P1363 conversion is rather trivial. You can see an example using the Crypto++ library at [ECDSA sign with BouncyCastle and verify with Crypto++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48783809/608639).

You might find [Cryptographic Interoperability: Digital Signatures](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25590/Cryptographic-Interoperability-Digital-Signatures) on Code Project helpful.

Comment: "Because you are using secp-521r1, both r and s must be 66 bytes. ". This is not correct for the X9.62 ASN.1 signature, which uses variable sized integers. It is however the maximum size, but only because 521 cannot be divided by 8 (otherwise an additional `00` byte to the left may be required so the integer encoding isn't interpreted to be a negative number).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - My bad, I was referring to the concatenation of `r || s`, and not the ASN.1 encoding. I added information on the field element size of secp-521r1.